# Program Close Python

Tags: python, unexpectendoffile

When I run this code from IDLE, it runs fine.  When I run the py file from the command line, I insert the file name and press **enter**, and the program closes.  Why is this happening?  Do I need to write some kind of pause function in the code, or is it something else?

```
def encrypt(file,key):
    count=0
    encrypt=[]
    tmp=[]        
    openfile=open(file,"rb")        
    msg=openfile.read()        
    openfile.close()

    for i in msg:
        if count>=len(key):
              count=0     
        encrypt.append(i^ord(key[count]))
        count+=1

    for i in range(len(encrypt)):
        tmp.append(encrypt[len(encrypt)-1-i])

    count=0
    encrypt[:]=[]

    for i in tmp:
        if count>=len(key):
              count=0

        encrypt.append(i^ord(key[count]))
        count+=1

    encryptmsg=''.join(chr(e) for e in encrypt)
    ext=input('Saving...File Name (with extension)? ')
    file= open(ext, "wb")
    file.write(str.encode(encryptmsg))
    file.close()

    input("Press Enter to Continue...")

ans = input("""
 1- Encrypt/Decrypt
 0-Exit
-:""")

file_to_encrypt = input("File? ")
key = input("Key? ")
if ans=='1':
    encrypt(file_to_encrypt,key)
else:
    quit()
```

Comment: So you see the "File?" prompt and respond, but never see the "Key?" prompt? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: yes, when it is supposed to go to the key prompt it just closes the program

Comment: Did you really means `str.encode(encryptmsg)`? That's a really silly way to say `encryptmsg.encode()` (which means the same thing as `encryptmsg.encode('utf-8')`), was that really your intent?

Comment: Also, just to be clear, is both IDLE and your interactive interpreter Python 3.x? `input` is the wrong function to use on 2.x, so if this is 2.x, you'd want `raw_input`. I'm worried your IDLE is 3.x, but your default Python interpreter for `.py` files might be 2.x, causing the problem.

Comment: I just started learning python, this is my first program so that is the only way i found to do what i wanted

Comment: the idle is python 3

Comment: @pedrosantos: If you're not sure what version is associated with `.py` files, try adding `import sys`, `print(sys.version_info)`, `sys.stdout.flush()` to your code at the very top, so they're the first thing executed. It should tell you what version you're running.

Comment: i think the interpreter might be 2.7, how do i fix it?

Comment: trying doing `python3 mypythonscript.py` instead of just `python`

Comment: I used those commands and it is 2,7

Comment: Try **which python** to get the path to your Python executable.  Then look in that directory for Python3 and invoke it by name.  I tried your code both ways, and it works in Python3, but fails (with an error message) in Python2.7

Comment: I added the path to the path variable but i cant seem to make it work on cmd so i can call it with python3

Comment: ok i got it running thanks